# Error "object not found" in user-defined function

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to make a function that gives me a cluster-robust standard-error.
I have fitted a model

```
library(readstata13)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(lmtest)
df = read.dta13("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/auto.dta")

fit= lm(price ~ mpg + rep78 + weight + factor(foreign) , data= df)
```

and without enclosing the following statements into a function I managed to run

```
#this one works
a<-cluster.vcov(fit, ~ foreign)
coeftest(fit, a)
```

However, when I try to put it in a function, it does not work anymore! Why?

```
#with function
clu<- function(fitmodel,clusterby ) {
require(multiwayvcov, quietly = TRUE)
require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
a<-cluster.vcov(fitmodel, ~ clusterby)
coeftest(fitmodel, a)
}

clu(fit,foreign)
```

The error I get is

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'clusterby' not found

Answer (score 2):

Its because it tries to find `clusterby` instead of `foreign`. You could do use `substitute` and `eval` to do it. You could do something like this inside your function:

```
clu<- function(fitmodel,clusterby ) {
  require(multiwayvcov, quietly = TRUE)
  require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
  a <- eval(substitute(cluster.vcov(fitmodel, ~ i),  list(i = as.name(clusterby))))
  # a<-cluster.vcov(fitmodel, ~ clusterby)
  coeftest(fitmodel, a)
}
```

Also, since `foreign` is not an object your function call should be like this:

```
clu(fit,"foreign")
```